# Inventory Management with doctrine and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, inventory

I'd like to make a database, with **doctrine**, with an interface in **PHP/Symfony2**.

It's a company that sells clothing. So we have a table **stock** with product elements and a table **Product** with all clothes.

Could you guide me where to start ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a good start: http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/

This tutorial shows you how to create a blog with ***Symfony***, ***Doctrine*** and ***Twig***. If you rename the **Blog** entity into **Product** and change it's properties to fit you product model you are good to go.

More on working with Doctrine in the official documentation here: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html

Comment: Hi, the link is broken to the tutorial, do you know of another one?